# Hide points on a rotating D3.Js globe

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to make a rotating and zoomable globe in D3.JS, based on this block https://bl.ocks.org/sarah37/d8a1722f7d9f2a40eb07a3e99bf3c0be. The zooming and spinning functionality works fine, but I'm also hoping to add points to the globe. I've figured out how to add the points from a CSV file, and gotten them on the correct lat/long coordinates. The problem however is that all the points are placed above the map, so while the countries will disappear over the globe, the points remain visible.

Obviously, I'd like to have the points disappear when their associated landmasses do.

I'm trying to make the points disappear based on their distance from the center of the map. For example, a point with a latitude greater than 90º from the center of the map would have fill set to none.

I can't however, seem to calculate this center point, and have it update as the globe rotates. I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution to this, or if anyone has any incite on how to calculate the lat/long of the center of the globe as it rotates.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Globe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mathsfunctions.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>

<div id="svgDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="globe.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Globe.JS

```
// width and height
// var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
// var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var w = 960;
var h = 500;

// scale globe to size of window
var scl = Math.min(w, h)/2.5; 

// map projection
var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
        .scale(scl)
        .translate([ w/2, h/2 ]);

// path generator
var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection);

// append svg
var svg = d3.select("#svgDiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

// append g element for map
var map = svg.append("g");

// enable drag
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged);

var gpos0, o0, gpos1, o1;
svg.call(drag);

// enable zoom
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.75, 50]) //bound zoom
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

// load topojson
d3.json("world-110m.json", function(json) {
    map.append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("class", "ocean")
    .attr("d", path);

    map.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.merge(json, json.objects.countries.geometries))
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path);

    map.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(json, json.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("class", "boundary")
    .attr("d", path);
});

//Add the city point data
d3.csv("us-cities2.csv", function(data) {
  map.selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
       return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
       return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
     })
     .attr("r", 2)
     .attr("class","city")
     .style("fill", "yellow")
     .style("stroke", "gray")
     .style("stroke-width", 0.25)
     .style("opacity", 0.75);         
});


// functions for dragging
function dragstarted() {
    gpos0 = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
    o0 = projection.rotate();
}

function dragged() {
    gpos1 = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
    // console.log("gpos0: "+gpos0+"and gpos1: "+gpos1)

    o0 = projection.rotate();
    o1 = eulerAngles(gpos0, gpos1, o0);
    projection.rotate(o1);

    map.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
    map.selectAll('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d){
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]
          })
          .attr('cy', function(d){
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]
          });
}

// functions for zooming
function zoomed() {
    projection.scale(d3.event.transform.translate(projection).k * scl)
    map.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
        map.selectAll('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d){
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]
          })
          .attr('cy', function(d){
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]
          });
}
```

mathsfunctions.js

```
// all functions are from http://bl.ocks.org/ivyywang/7c94cb5a3accd9913263

var to_radians = Math.PI / 180;
var to_degrees = 180 / Math.PI;


// Helper function: cross product of two vectors v0&v1
function cross(v0, v1) {
    return [v0[1] * v1[2] - v0[2] * v1[1], v0[2] * v1[0] - v0[0] * v1[2], v0[0] * v1[1] - v0[1] * v1[0]];
}

//Helper function: dot product of two vectors v0&v1
function dot(v0, v1) {
    for (var i = 0, sum = 0; v0.length > i; ++i) sum += v0[i] * v1[i];
    return sum;
}

// Helper function: 
// This function converts a [lon, lat] coordinates into a [x,y,z] coordinate 
// the [x, y, z] is Cartesian, with origin at lon/lat (0,0) center of the earth
function lonlat2xyz( coord ){

  var lon = coord[0] * to_radians;
  var lat = coord[1] * to_radians;

  var x = Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon);

  var y = Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon);

  var z = Math.sin(lat);

  return [x, y, z];
}

// Helper function: 
// This function computes a quaternion representation for the rotation between to vectors
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.E2.86.94_Quaternion
function quaternion(v0, v1) {

  if (v0 && v1) {

      var w = cross(v0, v1),  // vector pendicular to v0 & v1
          w_len = Math.sqrt(dot(w, w)); // length of w     

        if (w_len == 0)
          return;

        var theta = .5 * Math.acos(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, dot(v0, v1)))),

          qi  = w[2] * Math.sin(theta) / w_len; 
          qj  = - w[1] * Math.sin(theta) / w_len; 
          qk  = w[0]* Math.sin(theta) / w_len;
          qr  = Math.cos(theta);

      return theta && [qr, qi, qj, qk];
  }
}

// Helper function: 
// This functions converts euler angles to quaternion
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.E2.86.94_Quaternion
function euler2quat(e) {

  if(!e) return;

    var roll = .5 * e[0] * to_radians,
        pitch = .5 * e[1] * to_radians,
        yaw = .5 * e[2] * to_radians,

        sr = Math.sin(roll),
        cr = Math.cos(roll),
        sp = Math.sin(pitch),
        cp = Math.cos(pitch),
        sy = Math.sin(yaw),
        cy = Math.cos(yaw),

        qi = sr*cp*cy - cr*sp*sy,
        qj = cr*sp*cy + sr*cp*sy,
        qk = cr*cp*sy - sr*sp*cy,
        qr = cr*cp*cy + sr*sp*sy;

    return [qr, qi, qj, qk];
}

// This functions computes a quaternion multiply
// Geometrically, it means combining two quant rotations
// http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/arithmetic/index.htm
function quatMultiply(q1, q2) {
  if(!q1 || !q2) return;

    var a = q1[0],
        b = q1[1],
        c = q1[2],
        d = q1[3],
        e = q2[0],
        f = q2[1],
        g = q2[2],
        h = q2[3];

    return [
     a*e - b*f - c*g - d*h,
     b*e + a*f + c*h - d*g,
     a*g - b*h + c*e + d*f,
     a*h + b*g - c*f + d*e];

}

// This function computes quaternion to euler angles
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.E2.86.94_Quaternion
function quat2euler(t){

  if(!t) return;

  return [ Math.atan2(2 * (t[0] * t[1] + t[2] * t[3]), 1 - 2 * (t[1] * t[1] + t[2] * t[2])) * to_degrees, 
       Math.asin(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, 2 * (t[0] * t[2] - t[3] * t[1])))) * to_degrees, 
       Math.atan2(2 * (t[0] * t[3] + t[1] * t[2]), 1 - 2 * (t[2] * t[2] + t[3] * t[3])) * to_degrees
      ]
}

/*  This function computes the euler angles when given two vectors, and a rotation
  This is really the only math function called with d3 code.

  v0 - starting pos in lon/lat, commonly obtained by projection.invert
  v1 - ending pos in lon/lat, commonly obtained by projection.invert
  o0 - the projection rotation in euler angles at starting pos (v0), commonly obtained by projection.rotate
*/

function eulerAngles(v0, v1, o0) {

  /*
    The math behind this:
    - first calculate the quaternion rotation between the two vectors, v0 & v1
    - then multiply this rotation onto the original rotation at v0
    - finally convert the resulted quat angle back to euler angles for d3 to rotate
  */

  var t = quatMultiply( euler2quat(o0), quaternion(lonlat2xyz(v0), lonlat2xyz(v1) ) );
  return quat2euler(t); 
}
```

CSV containing cities:

```
rank,place,population,lat,lon
13,San Francisco,864816,37.777125,-122.419644
1000, Addis Adaba,20000,9.005401,38.763611
```

I expect the points to disappear behind the sphere, and I would be really grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: If you use a geoPath to display the points (you will have to pass a valid geojson point object to the path generator), rather than circles, the default clip angle of the orthographic projection hides the points on the far side, just as it hides any other feature on the far side.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so much more elegant. Thank you again!